# Can we dynamically set the value of "list" attribute of <apex:relatedList> component?

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

I am trying to design a generalized detail page for an object.

In the controller class I find the list of all child relations of that object.

I then want to create  for each child relations found and for accomplishing this I will have to dynamically set the value of list attribute within it.

For example :

```
<apex:relatedList subject={!ObjName} list="{!relatedListName}" />
```

But the problem here is that list attribute only accepts String literal, so can't implement it. Please suggest a way for this requirement to be accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying [apex:dataTable](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_dataTable.htm) or [apex:repeat](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_repeat.htm) to build your own list display.  You will likely need a [wrapper class](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class) to handle passing attributes and values from the sObject to the page.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can dynamically set the value of the "list" attribute on a relatedlist tag, and you do so via Dynamic Visualforce. This question has since been asked and concisely answered here on the Salesforce Stack exchange for any future browsers:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7531/apexrelatedlist-list-dontexistinallorgs-c-only-solveable-with-dynamic

Here is the general solution:

In a custom controller, add a function to dynamically generate the RelatedList markup. I will assume from your wording that you have already accessed the full list of child relationships in your controller, so in order to spit out all the lists in one block, I would use something like this:

```
public Component.Apex.OutputPanel getDynamicList() 
{
    Component.Apex.OutputPanel outPanel = new Component.Apex.OutputPanel();

    for(String id : childNames) {
       Component.Apex.RelatedList relList = new Component.Apex.RelatedList();
       relList.list = id;
       outPanel.childComponents.add(relList);
    }

    return outPanel;
}
```

In the middle there, you can dynamically set any string to the "List" value, and by iterating through your list of strings, you are adding related list objects over and over again. (To simply add one list, remove the for loop, and make the "id" string value whatever specific relationship you wish to display).

Then on your visualforce page, you can render this block out using a dynamic visualforce tag:

```
<apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!DynamicList}" />
```

(as you may know, the formulaic value field will dig up the getter automatically)

Great success!